# Boto: How do I use the 'tag' parameter of the AutoScalingGroup method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, autoscaling

The following code works. In other words, there is no error returned and a group is created. However, the instances launched by this group will not have a `Name` tag.

```
AS_GROUP = AutoScalingGroup(
    group_name=AS_GROUP_NAME,
    availability_zones=ZONE_LIST,
    launch_config=LAUNCH_CONFIG_NAME,
    min_size=GROUP_MIN_SIZE,
    max_size=GROUP_MAX_SIZE,
    default_cooldown=DEFAULT_COOLDOWN,
    desired_capacity=DESIRED_CAPACITY,
    tag=[Tag(
            key='Name',
            value='ASG Minion',
            propagate_at_launch=True,
            resource_id=AS_GROUP_NAME)],
    )
AS_CONNECTION.create_auto_scaling_group(AS_GROUP)
```

I have tried the `Tag` method without the `resource_id`.

```
[Tag(key="Name", value="ASGMinion", propagate_at_launch=True)]
```

Other obviously wrong ways I have also tried:

```
tag='k=Name, v=ASGMinion, p=true',
tag=['k=Name, v=ASGMinion, p=true'],
tag=[Tag('k=Name, v=ASGMinion, p=true')],
```

No worky.

Of course, I can run this after the group is already created:

```
tag = Tag(key='Name', value=tag_name, propagate_at_launch=True, resource_id=groups[group_number].name)
asConnection.create_or_update_tags([tag])
```

But that defeats the point of the `tag` parameter in the `AutoScalingGroup` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is rather embarrassing. The main problem was that the correct name of the parameter is `tags` and not `tag`. Once I got that sorted out I was able to run through and find which value this parameter was looking for. This is what works:

```
tags=[Tag(
        key='Name',
        value='ASG Minion',
        propagate_at_launch=True,
        resource_id=AS_GROUP_NAME)],
)
```

I tried it also without the `resource_id` and it complained with `Invalid resourceID: None`. So the group name needs to be specified in the tag even if the group is the being created at the same time. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else.