# Naming instance on auto scaling with Boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, autoscaling

Is there a way which I can put name also to the instances which are created through autoscaling. I know we can put tag name with this [Boto: How do I use the 'tag' parameter of the AutoScalingGroup method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766867/boto-how-do-i-use-the-tag-parameter-of-the-autoscalinggroup-method)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [create_or_update_tags(tags)](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/autoscale.html#boto.ec2.autoscale.AutoScaleConnection.create_or_update_tags) function to add or edit tags for instances in an existing AutoScaling Group.